# How to auto height viewport child panels in it?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, border-layout, extjs4.2

I am working in ExtJS4. I am getting stuck at a point where I want to auto height the east region of border layout. Actually my requirement is to automatically increase height of any region based on child elemtents content inside it. I tried a lot but I did not get solution for it. Please give me some suggestion.

In my code I am just testing a simple code containing 5 panels in east region, out of those four panels are displayed. The fifth panel is not displayed, how can I make it visible? I am just using a sample code for reference.

Here is my viewport code :

```
Ext.define('Am.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'border',
    id:'viewportId',
    alias:'widget.Viewport',
    autoScroll:true,

       //        closable:true,
               items: [
                       {
                           region:'north',
                                       items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'panel',
                                      flex:.2,
                                      title:'north region',
                                      html:'<p>north region'
                                  }

                                  ]//end of items

                       },
                       {
                           region:'west',
                           id:'westId',
                           //margins:'0 5 5 5',
                           flex:.3,
                           //layout:'accordion',
                           items:[
                                              {
                                      title:'This day in a history',
                                      xtype:'Content'
                                  }

                                  ]//end if items
                       },// end of region west
                       {
                           //title:'center',
                           region:'center',
                           id:'centerId',
                           //html:'center region',
                           items:[
                                  ]//End of itmes
                       },// end of region center
                       {
                           region:'east',
                           id:'eastId',
                           //margins:'0 5 0 5',
                           flex:.3,
                           //layout:'accordion',
                           items:[
                                  {
                                      xtype:'panel',
                                      title:'panel1',
                                      html:'hi<br>hello<br>good<br><br><br><br><br>morning<br>nice<br>looking',
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'panel',
                                      title:'panel2',
                                      html:'hi<br>hello<br>good<br><br><br><br<br>noon<br>nice<br>looking',
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'panel',
                                      title:'panel3',
                                      html:'hi<br>hello<br>good<br><br><br><br><brafter noon<br>nice<br>looking'
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'panel',
                                      title:'panel4',
                                      html:'hi<br>hello<br>good<br><br><br><br><br><br><brnigth<br>nice<br>looking'
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'panel',
                                      title:'panel5',
                                      html:'good bye'
                                  },
                                  ]//end if items
                       },
                       {
                           //title:'South',
                           region:'south',
                           id:'southId',
                           items:[{
                                  xtype:'panel',
                                  title:"footer",
                                  html:'footer '
                           }]
                       },//mainMenu   // used mainMenu when you are using mainMenu variable
                       ]//end if items
});//End of view port
```

And here is my screen shot output :
[image]

Child component panel5 is not displayed. How can I make it visible?
How can I display all panels with this requirement? I want to make auto increase the size of east region based on panel contents.
Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: read up on vbox layout

Comment: I read and implement but still not get problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

## To get a panel to autoresize based on its content

You should set its `flex` to 0, and make sure other panels have `flex` that is different from 0. So in the following code, the footer has `flex: 0` and the center region has `flex: 1`; the footer will therefore resize based on its contents. Here's a [working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmuhH/2/):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Border Layout',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'Footer',
        region:'south',
        xtype: 'panel',
        margins: '5 0 0 5',
        flex: 0, // Notice this.
        id: 'footer',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch',
            pack  : 'start',
        },
        items:[{
            title: '1',
            height: 50
        },{
            title: '2',
            height: 50                                   
        }]
    },{
        title: 'Center Region',
        flex: 1, // Notice this.
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: 'fit',
        margins: '5 5 0 0'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.getCmp('footer').add({
    title: '3',
    height: 50                        
});
```

## To get a panel of fixed size to scroll based on its content

Simply add `autoScroll: true` on the containers (the region panels).

Here's some working code, which you can see in action on [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/pmuhH/):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Border Layout',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'West Region',
        region:'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        margins: '5 0 0 5',
        width: 200,
        id: 'west-region-container',

        // Notice the next line
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch',
            pack  : 'start',
        },
        items:[{
            title: '1',
            height: 100
        },{
            title: '2',
            height: 100            
        },{
            title: '3',
            height: 100                        
        }]
    },{
        title: 'Center Region',
        region: 'center', 
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: 'fit',
        margins: '5 5 0 0'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: thanks Izhaki. It works.But my requirement is I don't want scroll bar at east region.I want to make my footer flexible in such way that if the length of my child component increases, the footer should also get auto extended in downward direction and vice versa..please provide me solution

Comment: yeah!!  Izhaki it works for me.But it size is varying between width and height i.e. 1000*1000.It not increasing more than it.But I want to increase its height in downward direction and display all contents in view.actually I want to make infinite scrolling in center region and footer moves in downward direction based on center regions child component.I want output like this link --> http://ext4all.com/post/tag/extjs-4-1-0   .... please give some advise..

Comment: @Izhaki: Tried this but not worked. Will you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137062/to-make-ext-gridpanel-resizeable-inside-ext-window-in-ext-js

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `flex` config setting:

```
    items:[{
        title: 'panel1',
        flex: .3
    },{
        title: 'panel2',
        flex: .3
    },{
        title: 'panel3',
        flex: .4
    }]
```

Comment: thanks peter.But I allready used flex but it not satisfied my requirement.I want to make footer flexible(upward or downward) based on the child component.

Comment: I answer to your "How can I make the child component panel5 displayed?" Maybe, have we finally got to the final goal? Sorry, but your question asks nothing about this. Can you make your question clear?

Answer (score 0):

this works (for your first problem at least):

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.MyViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    region: 'center'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    width: 150,
                    title: 'My Panel',
                    region: 'west'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    width: 150,
                    layout: {
                        align: 'stretch',
                        type: 'vbox'
                    },
                    region: 'east',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'My Panel',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'My Panel',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'My Panel',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'My Panel',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'My Panel',
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 50,
                    title: 'My Panel',
                    region: 'north'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 50,
                    title: 'My Panel',
                    region: 'south'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

[image]